# How to do mathematical symbols in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, math, typesetting

I'm using bootstrap to make a website, I'm using Bootstrap as a nice framework and I'm wondering how to do mathematical symbols, such as the algebraic version of x, as well as alpha, beta and gamma.

Not to mention it would be helpful to show indices, for example 3^2 would just look like it would if you were to write it.

Comment: This is not related to bootstrap, i think you have to create your own using images or something else or using another library (if exist).

Comment: This doesn't need to be Twitter Bootstrap (retagged) specific (though idk if something exists built-in) - you can load something like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)

Comment: Use [**HTML entities**](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/) or [**Unicode**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm).

Comment: Or use the symbol font if it renders in HTML or use a google math font:

Comment: It depends on how far you need to go. If it's inline mathematical symbol, HTML codes will work. But if you need some advanced symbol, look for a javascript library to do that

Answer (score 3):

There are HTML entities for mathematical symbols, 
check out this

Mnemonic  output  code

```
&alpha;     = α     &#945;  
&beta;      = β     &#946;  
&gamma;     = γ     &#947;
&times;     = ×     &#215;
&sup2;      = x²    &#178;
```

[this](http://www.dionysia.org/html/entities/symbols.html)
and
[also this](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This list is long and i don't all the ones he will need. Searching for "HTML entities for mathematical symbols" will be a guide if the linked page changes

Comment: I would still recommend putting the requested symbols and maybe a few more right in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have plenty of options to choose from - here are a few solid ones:

1. Try out JavaScript-based approaches to convert symbols to pretty mathematical symbols
2. Generate images from text
3. Go for simple linearized notation - no images/javascript, just HTML

All options have their merits. Here are a few resources for each option:

1. JavaScript

   1. [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) - A small, quick library that makes it easy to put formatted mathematical expressions in web pages.
   2. [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) - An open source JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all browsers.
   3. Plenty more - there's more information [at W3C's MathML page](http://www.w3.org/Math/).
2. Images from text:

   1. Try something [TeX based](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html)
   2. [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica//),
   3. You'll most likely get the images in a PostScript format. Sometimes it's better to use a GIF format, since it is much more widely sup­port­ed in browsers by default.
3. No images/javascript - just HTML

   1. Like the previous answer, there are [Mathematical Symbols in Unicode](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/math.html).

A lot of the options that I described came from [this link](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/).

If you're thinking of doing a wide variety of mathematical formulas, option #1 could be the way to go. If you use something that supports a wide swath of browsers (e.g., MathJax), then you might have a solid solution.